# Are there more than two rational solutions to $a^b= b^a$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have wondered for a while if there are any interesting rational solutions to $a^b = b^a$. I have tried but cannot find any solutions other than $a=2$ and $b=4$, or vice versa.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't close this problem as it received many votes and some good answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an infinite number of rational solutions
$$a=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n,\;\;b=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n+1},\;\;n\in\mathbb{Z},\;\;0\neq n\neq -1.$$

For a proof that these are *all* the rational solutions of $a^b=b^a$ with $a\neq b$, see [Marta Sved's article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Sved50816668.pdf) (1990). As she describes, this question has a long history, it was first answered by Euler in 1748 and has been generalized in various ways.

I show a screen shot from [Euler's proof](https://archive.org/details/introductioanaly00eule_0/page/294) that there is an infinite number of rational solutions (Euler uses the word "innumerabilia" -- uncountable, obviously not in the technical sense of the word).

[image][image]

Comment: There's only a beginning of proof in your link, not a full proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been looking at this problem for so long, it feels stupid how simple the solution is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi --- changed the link to a complete proof

Comment: Innumerabilia in Latin means countless and that sounds like a word that Euler would have used to mean infinite. I don't know what Latin word is used by modern users of Latin for the mathematical notion of uncountable.

Answer (score 11):

There are infinitely many solutions.

For example, take any positive integer $n$ and set $c=(n+1)/n, a=c^n, b=c^{n+1}$.
Then 
$$
a^b=c^{nb}=c^{nc^{n+1}}
$$
and
$$
b^a=c^{(n+1)a}=c^{(n+1)c^n}.
$$

These two expressions are equal because

$$
nc^{n+1}=(nc)c^n=(n+1)c^n.
$$